# string-splitting and arrays

Tags: c#

In this program for storing high scores I want the user to input a player's name and high score in a single line, for example "eric 87". 
After the user enters the last player's name and score, it should then list all at once the scores that were entered. I don't know how to do this when splitting strings like "eric 97". Thanks very much for any help!

```
const int MAX = 20;
static void Main()
{
    string[ ] player = new string[MAX];
    int index = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("High Scores ");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter each player's name followed by his or her high score.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter without input when finished.");

    do {
        Console.Write("Player name and score: ", index + 1);
        string playerScore = Console.ReadLine();
        if (playerScore == "")
            break;
        string[] splitStrings = playerScore.Split();
        string n = splitStrings[0];
        string m = splitStrings[1];


    } while (index < MAX);

    Console.WriteLine("The scores of the player are: ");
    Console.WriteLine("player \t Score \t");

  //  Console.WriteLine(name + " \t" + score);
    // scores would appear here like:
    // george 67
    // wendy 93
    // jared 14
```

Comment: I'm assuming there's a reason you aren't asking for name and score separately(aka the easy/lazy option)?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code you didn't put your player array to use. 
However, I would suggest a more object oriented approach.

```
public class PlayerScoreModel
{
    public int Score{get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Store the player and scores in a `List<PlayerScoreModel>`.

And when the last user and score has been entered.. simply iterate through the list.

```
 do {
        Console.Write("Player name and score: ", index + 1);
        string playerScore = Console.ReadLine();
        if (playerScore == "")
            break;
        string[] splitStrings = playerScore.Split();
        PlayerScoreModel playerScoreModel = new PlayerScoreModel() ;

        playerScoreModel.Name = splitStrings[0];
        playerScoreModel.Score = int.Parse(splitStrings[1]);
        playerScoreModels.Add(playerScoreModel) ;

    } while (somecondition);

   foreach(var playerScoreModel in playerScoreModels)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(playerScoreModel.Name +" " playerScoreModel.Score) ;
    }
```

Provide error checking as necessary.